# Capitalize letter following a number using preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert a pattern like "5a " into "5A ". This pattern may appear at the beginning or middle of a larger string. I've tried this:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback("/(0-9)([a-z]) /", function($matches) {
  return $matches[1].strtoupper($matches[2]).' ';
}, $string);
```

But it doesn't work. No error - the string just stays as "5a ". Can you see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(0-9)([a-z]) /
```

should be

```
/([0-9])([a-z]) /
```

Comment: Duh! Working now. Thanks very much. :)